# why string a gets appended to string b in this code

Tags: c

i am writing a basic c program to display two strings, one taken from user i.e "a" and the other being defined in code "b" but when i run the code below string "a" gets appended to "b". why? and what is that symbol at end of "a"

updated code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{ 
char a[ 5 ];
int i=0;

while(i<5)

{
     a[i]=getchar();
     i++;
     }

   char b[]={'r','f','s','/0'};

 printf("output:-");
  printf("\n %s",a);
 printf("\n %s",b);
 return 0;
```

console

```
qwert

output:-qwert$

  rfs$qwert$
```

there is a some special symbol instead of $ above, what is it?

Comment: `while(i<6)` That overflows the `a` buffer as it accesses `a[5]`. `5` is an out of bounds index. Also, strings in C need to be `\0` (`NUL`) terminated. Which `a` and `b` are not. So you cannot treat them as strings (as is being done with the `%s` directive).

Comment: i've made the following changes:- added '/0' as last element of b and while(i<5).Still getting the same output.

Comment: Please update your question to show the actual code. Avoid just describing code in words as that is almost always ambiguous. For example, did you or did you not NUL terminate `a`? And did you really terminate with `'/0` when it is supposed to be `'\0'`? It is not clear. So show the exact code and there will be no doubts.

Comment: @techvigil sounds like your string is still too short. You index up to `4` but there is still no room for the terminator. `a` is still unterminated.

Comment: Right, with the actual code we can see you didn't NUL terminate `a` and you used the wrong terminator for `b`.

Comment: ok, got it i was terminating "b" wrongly '/0' instead of '\0' .thnx

Comment: Aside: usually put you `newline` at the *end* of each line, not at the start. So it would be `printf("output:-\n"); printf(" %s\n",a); printf(" %s\n",b);`

Comment: ok, but i still don't get why the output is showing a "box with dot inside" like character at end of "a". it shows up even if enter 2,3 or 4 characters in "a"

Comment: Like we have already told you. You have not NUL terminated `a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting all the comments into an answer. The problems in the original code stem mostly from not NUL terminating the character arrays to produce valid C strings.

- `a` is not NUL terminated. Can fix by increasing the `a` array by 1 and explicitly writing a NUL to the last byte.
- `b` is not NUL terminated. Can fix by initialising `b` using a literal string or a char array with `'\0'` as the last byte. The example below uses the former.

Here is the full code with the errors corrected. Note that the code to read input is fragile as it only accepts exactly a 5 character string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void)
{ 
    char a[6];
    int i=0;

    while (i<5) {
        a[i]=getchar();
        i++;
    }
    a[i] = '\0';

    char b[]="rfs";

    printf("output:-\n");
    printf(" %s\n",a);
    printf(" %s\n",b);

   return 0;
}
```